# Peculiar behavior with -1 and pow

Tags: rust

I was debugging some code to compute the determinant of a matrix, and was sorely disappointed when I found the cause. Simply put, this code:

```
-1i64.pow(i as u32)
```

always results in `-1`. I found that I could use `i64::pow` instead, or wrap `-1i64` in parentheses to solve the issue:

```
i64::pow(-1, i as u32)
(-1i64).pow(-1, i as u32)
```

I'm disappointed and sad-mad because rustc told me to use the first example:

```
  |
3 |         println!("{}", -1.pow(i as u32));
  |                              ^^^
  |
help: you must specify a concrete type for this numeric value, like `i32`
  |
3 |         println!("{}", -1_i32.pow(i as u32));
  |                            ~~~~~
```

I tried with and without the underscore and they both still always result in -1. My question is, why is this the case? What purpose do the parentheses serve here? What does `-1i64.pow(i as u32)` *actually* do? I could not find anything in the documentation, Rust book, or Stack Overflow.

[Here's a playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=f7ea80cc89338ebde81705086d88fe5d)

Comment: With the answer in mind, this *is* in the documentation via [expression precedence](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/expressions.html#expression-precedence) (method calls have a higher precedence than the unary `-` operator)

Comment: @Amadan Thanks for the hint, I've found the [relevant documentation](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/expressions.html#expression-precedence). I come from JavaScript and we can't do `2.someMethod()` so I didn't know what to expect :)

Comment: Added some discussion on JavaScript :)

Comment: Actually Rust's order of operations isn't weird here at all: in math it works the same way: `-x^y` means `-(x^y)` not `(-x)^y`...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your code parses as `-(1.pow(...))`. `1.pow(...)` is `1`. Negating `1` produces `-1`. Parentheses change precedence, as usual, so `pow` is sent to `-1`, not `1`.

> I'm disappointed and sad-mad because rustc told me to use the first example:

Rust does not know whether you want to negate `1` or `1.pow(...)`, so your disappointment is displaced :P

---

Addendum regarding JavaScript:

> I come from JavaScript and we can't do `2.someMethod()`

Of course you can call methods on numbers; but JavaScript will complain if you do it on `1` because it will always expect the first dot to be the decimal dot, so if calling methods directly on number literals you have to make them float (i.e. `1.toString()` is bad, `1.0.toString()` is good, as are `(1).toString()` and `1..toString()`).

Now, `Number` doesn't have a method `pow`, but we can make it (for demonstration purposes only, because changing built-in prototypes is not a recommended practice):

```
Number.prototype.pow = function(p) { return Math.pow(this, p) }
```

Now you have the same situation as in Rust:

```
-1.0.pow(2)
# => -1
(-1.0).pow(2)
# => 1
```

Comment: Seems really simple now. I think the `i64` suffix was just adding to the confusion. Anyways, waiting to accept this answer was the longest 6 minutes I've ever waited in my life.